# VBA - How can I paste the data from the last modified file in a folder to another workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

Project for work but I can't get the data over. I previously copied the worksheets from one report to another, but I need info from multiple workbooks to be dumped into the same worksheet.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Sub GetMostRecentFile()

Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
Dim objFile As File
Dim myFolder
Dim strFilename As String
Dim dteFile As Date
 Dim SDrv   As String
Dim DDrv   As String
Dim Sfname As String
Dim Dfname As String
Dim wkbSrc As Workbook
Dim wkbDst As Workbook

Const myDir As String = "INSERT SOURCE FOLDER HERE"


Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject
Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)



dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
    If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
        dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
        strFilename = objFile.Name
    End If
Next objFile

Set FileSys = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing


SDrv = myDir
Sfname = strFilename

DDrv = "INSERT TARGET DIRECTORY HERE"
Dfname = "MainReport.xlsm"

Set wkbSrc = Workbooks.Open(SDrv & Sfname)
Set wkbDst = ThisWorkbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

The following line gives me an error "application defined or object defined error"

```
wkbSrc.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy After:=wkbDst.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value

wkbSrc.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
After:=
```

Is for copying sheets, not ranges.  Eliminate it and see what happens.  That, or eliminate the ranges:

```
wkbSrc.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=wkbDst.Worksheets(1)
```